# Excel Macro to write a formula result to a cell

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I know how to write a formula to cell in a MACRO, but i need to write the output of this formula to the cell

```
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(IF(RC[-1]<>"""",RC[-2]& _ MID(CELL(""filename"",RC),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",RC))+1,256),""""),""_"",RC[-1])"
```

without using

```
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Copy
Rng.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _ SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

I always just overwrite the value of the cell with its current value, so for example:

```
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(IF(RC[-1]<>"""",RC[-2]& _
    MID(CELL(""filename"",RC),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",RC))+1,256),""""),""_"",RC[-1])"
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

This will remove the formula from the cell and simply replace it with the value calculated by the formula.