# Write value of formula into cell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

If i want value from a Excel formula intoa cell and only value not " The formula"

I have try with this code but it gives me not only the value.

```
Dim ZmAntal As Long

Dim CountryRange As Range, C As Range

Dim Res As Variant 

ZmAntal = Worksheets("Maskinerum").Cells(8, 4).value 

Set CountryRange = Sheets("Zmbistad").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ZmAntal, 1))

For Each C In CountryRange

    Res = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],RC[14])"

    If Not IsError(Res) Then         

        C.Offset(0, 0).value = Res

    End If

Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Macro to write a formula result to a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41122891/11683)

Answer (score 1):

you could use this:

```
Dim ZmAntal As Long

ZmAntal = Worksheets("Maskinerum").Cells(8, 4).Value
With Sheets("Zmbistad").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ZmAntal, 1)) ' reference relevant range
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],RC[14])" ' write formula in referenced range
    .Value = .Value ' get rid of formulas and leave values only in referenced range
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).ClearContents ' clear any cell with an "error" value n referenced range
End With
```

Comment: Deleted my post as it was essentially the same code.

Comment: if i want value to be text some of the formula give result more then 15 digi numbers?

Comment: @KjeldOstersen, please explain in better detail your issue about _text value_ and _15 digit numbers_

Comment: @KjeldOstersen, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Evaluate`:

```
'...
With CountryRange
    .Value = Evaluate("=IF(ROW()," & _
                            "CONCATENATE(" & .Offset(0, 1).Address & "," & _
                                        "" & .Offset(0, 14).Address & "))")
End With
'...
```